How to wait for subscriber to finish TEXT_EVENT_STREAM on Java Spring
Working with a Stream API that return Strings, I want to have a function that returns them on a single String separated by a delimeter, currently using a subscribe and appending to a List<String> but obviusly since is an async wont wait to have it ready before returning on the function.
How can I accomplish an non-async method?
private String executeStream(String streamId, UserToken currentUserAndToken) {

    List<String> combinedString = new ArrayList<String>();

    URI streamUri = UriComponentsBuilder.newInstance()
        .scheme("https")
        .host(host)
        .path(streamPath)
        .buildAndExpand(streamVariablesMap)
        .toUri();

    webClientt.get()
        .uri(streamUri)
        .headers(h -> h.setBearerAuth(currentUserAndToken.getToken()))
        .accept(MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM) // for Server-Sent Events (SSE)
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToFlux(String.class) // convert the response body to a Flux
        .subscribe(data -> combinedString.add(data)); // < --- Here I want to combine all Data into single string

    return String.join(", ", combinedString);
}

Update:
If I use .blockLast() insted of subscribe. I get the following error:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: block()/blockFirst()/blockLast() are blocking, which is not supported in thread reactor-http-nio-3

Use .blockLast() instead .subscribe() It will block until you read all. This will make your call synchronous. See https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#blockLast--

If i use .blockLast() which returns a String, I am getting this error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: block()/blockFirst()/blockLast() are blocking, which is not supported in thread reactor-http-nio-3.

I think it is because Jetty does not allow blocking. Probably you need Tomcat for that. Do you Jetty ?

This is a third party endpoint I am doing the GET, not sure on which platform it is developed. What I can say is that I have examples working with RestTemplate instead of WebClient

May be this helps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78099730/how-to-block-reactor-http-thread-while-calling-third-party-api-using-spring-bo The idea is to block in other thread then reactor
